# Django reverse error: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I've looked at a lot of different posts, but they're all either working with a different version of django or don't seem to work. Here is what I'm trying to do:

urls.py (for the entire project):

```
    from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

urls.py (specific to the app):

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('' ,
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.posts, name="postdetail"),

)
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published=True)
    return render(request,'blog/index.html',{'posts':posts})

def posts(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html',{'post':post})
```

And finally the template:

```
 {% block title %} Blog Archive {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        <h1> My Blog Archive </h1>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <h2>
                <a href="{% url "postdetail" slug=post.slug %}">
                    {{post.title}}
                </a>
            </h2>
            <p>{{post.description}}</p>
            <p>
                Posted on
                <time datetime="{{post.created|date:"c"}}">
                    {{post.created|date}}
                </time>
            </p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

For some reason this gives me a "No reverse Match": Reverse for 'postdetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'third'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

I've already tried getting rid of the double quotes around `postdetail` in the template, and I've also tried referring to it by the view name instead of the pattern name. Still no luck. The documentation isn't too helpful either.

Help is really appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You've used a namespace when including the URLs, so you probably need to use `"blog:postdetail"` to reverse it.

Comment: I can't believe I was stuck on that for so long. I was trying "blog:posts" and variations of that all this while. Thank you!

Comment: If you use `django-extensions`, there's a handy management command that shows you all the configured URLS: `show_urls`.