# Django: - NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, html, django, namespaces, web

I'm following the djangoforgirls.org tutorial on making my first django site. I'm trying the stage "extending your template" to make a link to an article within my website that uses the general template.

I keep get thrown the error:  "NoReverseMatch at /, Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P\d+)/$']"

Some variable and file names may seem strange, the use of the website was music sampling but I used the tutorial's names for things in case that was what was wrong.

My urls.py for entire project:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('sample.urls')),
]
```

My urls.py for the specific app (sample):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

My views.py for the app:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import AudioSample
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def post_list(request):
    samples = AudioSample.objects.order_by('length')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'samples': samples})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(AudioSample, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {'post': post})
```

And the line of code from the base template that's the link to another page in the website:

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">How to sample</a>
```

I saw another person that asked this question with a similar project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889242/django-reverse-error-noreversematch) and got it fixed but I dont understand the answer enough to make the change to mine (I dont understand what the namespace is).

Comment: <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">How to sample</a>.try this instead of keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one urls.py, namespace can tell django how to handle the request. So in normally, namespace is the APP name.

Answer (score 0):

In your project urls.py, try replacing `r''` with `r'^'`. The former matches *all* urls, while the latter matches the start of the string.